# Proof verification: Suppose $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is monotone. Prove that if $f(D)$ is an interval, then $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I am working through a theorem in Advanced Calculus, Fitzpatrick. Ch3, Theorem 3.23

> Suppose $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is monotone. Prove that if $f(D)$ is an interval, then $f$ is continuous

I solved it a different way than the book, I am looking for confirmation that my method is valid. If not, where did I go wrong?

**My attempt**
I will just do the case when $f$ is monotone increasing.

Assume $f(D)$ is an interval. Our goal is to prove $$\forall x \in D \quad \{x_n\} \text { converges to } x \rightarrow \{f(x_n)\} \text{ converges to } f(x)$$

Let $x$ be arbitrary element of $D$ and assume there exists a sequence $\{x_n\} \subset D$ that converges to $x$. There exists a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$, call it $\{x_{n_k}\}$, that is monotone increasing. It can be shown that since $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$, then $\{x_{n_k}\}$ converges to $sup \{x_{n_k}\} = x$.

Since $f$ is monotonic increasing, $\{f(x_{n_k})\}$ is monotonic increasing. Note that this implies $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, f(x_{n_k}) \leq f(x)$, since $x$ is the supremum of the subsequence. Therefore $\{f(x_{n_k})\}$ is a bounded monotonic sequence, which converges to $sup  \{f(x_{n_k})\} = f(x)$.

Therefore we have shown $\{f(x_{n_k})\}$ converges to $f(x)$ for arbitrary $x \in D$.

Comment: There exists a subsequence that is monotone increasing.  No, but the other possibility is: a subsequence that is monotone decreasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That proof cannot be correct because you did not use the fact that $f(D)$ is an interval (and the statement is surely wrong without that condition).

It is correct that $f(x_{n_k})$ increasing implies that $f(x_{n_k}) \to \sup  \{f(x_{n_k})\}$, but $f(x_{n_k}) \le f(x)$ for all $k$ implies only that the supremum is $\le f(x)$. You have not shown that the limit is *equal* to $f(x)$.

Another (minor) error is that an arbitrary sequence converging to $x$ does not necessarily have an increasing subsequence.

You *can* use your approach to show that $f$ has a left and a right limit at $x$. Then assume that these are different, i.e.
$$
 \lim_{y \to x-} f(x) < \lim_{y \to x+} f(x) \, .
$$
Now show that $f$ does not take values between those limits, contradicting the assumption that $f(D)$ is an interval.

Comment: Appreciate the help. I'm wondering now if I can rescue it, because if sup != f(x), then that defines an interval [sup, f(x)]  in f(D).

Comment: Regarding the increasing subsequence, there is a theorem 2.32 in the book that says "Every sequence has a monotone subsequence", which is what I used in that step

Comment: @YetiMountainButter: It is correct that every sequence has a monotone subsequence. But that is not necessarily *increasing.* – I have updated the answer with a sketch about how your argument can be rescued.

Comment: Thanks @Martin R, can you add a little more detail to your suggested approach? I don't see how we can show $f$ has a left and right limit at $x$

Comment: Oh wait, is it because the subsequence is either monotone increasing or monotone decreasing? So it approaches $x$ either from right or left?

Comment: For every sequence $(x_n)$ which approaches $x$ from the left, $f(x_n)$ converges to $\sup \{ f(t) \mid t < x \}$.